# Devise, can't log out

Tags: devise, activeadmin

In a Rails app, I use devise to manage my users and my link to destroy a session no longer work. It was working, and now I have add active admin, It doesn't.

My link is

```
<%= link_to "Déconnexion",  destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => 'button'  %>
```

My routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"}
```

My rake routes

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)
```

And it try to open the view /users/sign_out, so I have :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

Couldn't find User with id=sign_out
```

Does Active_admin and Devise crash together?
It will be weird 'cause active use devise, no?

Edit:

For the next person who will have this issue, I solved it by adding the next line to /config/initializers/devise.rb.

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Not exactly the finest way, but it does the job.

Comment: I think you have solved the problem very well under ActiveAdmin.

Comment: I solved this very similar issue by changing initializers/active_admin.rb and setting `config.logout_link_method = :delete`

Answer (score 3):

Posting Jeff Paquette's comment as an answer.

Update the `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` with:

```
config.logout_link_method = :delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make changes in your routes.rb :-

```
devise_scope :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"} do
  get "/users/sign_out", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
end
```

I am also getting same problem, only this can resolve me after 1hr time wasting.

Thanks.